# Are static methods more efficient?

Tags: c#, performance, static-methods

In terms of memory and time, is it better to make a method static?

Comment: To answer your question: yes, but you shouldn't ever take that into consideration.  See LBushkin's answer.

Comment: Completely reworded the question. It sounded like you were referring to the actual process of making a method static. ;) Refactoring tools make this process faster!

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Usually yes, there is no need to pass the "this" reference.  That reference is passed in the ECX register so there is no additional stack space required.  The register is already set if you make the call from an instance method of the same class, there will be no savings at all.  But it can help relieving the pressure on a x86 CPU core when the method is in another class, x86 doesn't have a lot of registers.  Seeing a measurable perf improvement would be exceedingly rare.

I do religiously mark methods of a class that don't use instance members as static.  I value the inherent contract provided by the static keyword: "this method does not mutate the object state."

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph – this is really what matters here and it makes `static` invaluable.

Comment: modern x86 cpus use register aliasing.

Comment: I agree with this answer, especially about the object state contract. In my code, if a method can be marked static, then I will so mark it, just to make it easier to reason about the program's behavior. Of course, static (non-object) state can still be mutated, which will complicate the analysis, somewhat. I solve this by always putting locks around static state mutation. This doesn't directly help the analysis, but it does encourage me to rethink the design and get rid of the state mutation!

Comment: To me your answer is very logical, but I see a lot of people calling static a pure code smell.

Comment: Logic trumps opinion any day.

Answer (score 59):

**You should make a method static if it does not require any state information from the class that it is part of.**

*If you don't care about polymorphism*, you can write any method as either instance or static by just deciding whether to take class instance members and pass them to the method as arguments. *What you should consider*, is whether the syntax is natural, whether the code is easy to understand and meaningful, and so on.

You probably shouldn't worry about optimizing at this level, because the performance overhead of a instance vs. static method is negligible. Yes, there's some space used in the dispatch table for the type (if the method is virtual) - but it's a tiny, constant overhead. Yes, there's also a tiny overhead in invoking an instance method versus a static method - but again it's tiny.

This seems like a level of micro-optimization, that unless you have measurable, tangible evidence to believe is actually affecting program performance, you should avoid. In fact, if you do things wrong, the cost of passing in additional parameters (copying them onto the stack, etc) rather than accessing them through the hidden `this` reference of your type, may result in *worse* performance.

*You are better of analyzing the semantics of the method, and making the static/instance decision on that basis.*

Comment: It is my understanding that the IL code that Microsoft C# generates uses the virtual dispatch (callvirt) for all instance methods whether it's virtual or not, even for sealed classes. This is to use callvirt's built-in null-checking. Otherwise, a null check would have to be coded, since the CLR has no problem calling an instance method on a null instance.

Comment: Yes, but theoretically, the jitter can inline non-virtual methods in certain cases. It can also do some static analysis to replace `callvirt` in cases like sealed classes, and so on. I'm not sure to what extent it actually does this, but it is possible.

Comment: To quote the Great Jeff Atwood - You can write Fortran in any language.

Comment: @Jeffrey, the `callvirt` has to be used for calls across assembly boundaries because making method virtual is a non-breaking change (whereas making it virtual->non-virtual would be). Due to the fact that a method being virtual is explicit in the CLI (as opposed to implicit in the JVM), even in non-optimizing mode the JIT can determine whether to use direct or indirect dispatch. The only overhead is then the null check, which is all but free on current processors.

Comment: I try to not make methods static just for the hell of it - mostly because I like polymorphism and it makes unit tests easier to write. If it makes good semantic to have the method be static then I do it, but I find that's actually kind of a rare case.

Comment: @Egor: it seems to me that a static method is easier to unit test, because there is no state - everything is supplied in the arguments.

Comment: To quote myself: Jeff wrote VB code till recently. To mention Fortan, you have to work with it and write a good compiler that no one with VB background did (to my knowledge). And probably never will.. It's not about Fortan anyway, it's about beating OOD to a pulp :)

Comment: @Mathias: Yes, the static methods themselves are easy to test, but you can't override them and replace them with stubs. For example, if your static method hits the database and you are testing the class you can't override it and have it return a pre-populated collection. But these are just details really, and different test strategies would take care of that situation. I guess I'm just in the 'don't like static methods' camp.

Answer (score 10):

If you are going to pass in the instance anyway (`SomeStaticMethod(obj, "abc", 123);`), then not really. You could only usefully use a static method in a scenario without polymorphism, and in such cases it is highly likely that any *simple* things like properties would have been inlined anyway.

Use objects "naturally" (`obj.SomeMethod("abc",123);`) - keep the code simple, and **profile** to find performance issues - it is **very** unlikely to be in the difference between instance and static unless you are running some *very* tight loops. There *are* some scenarios where it might matter, but they are pretty specialised.

Answer (score 7):

There is little to no difference between a static method and a non-virtual instance method. The latter just has the `this` prointer/reference as a "hidden" argument. In the generated machine code, both kinds of calls look very similar.

**A method should be static if it does not depend on/modify the object.**

Virtual methods (overridable) on the other hand require the caller to look up the exact implementation in the so called [vtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vtable). In addition to preventing the compiler from inlining very small methods (simple property accessors are inlined very often) the lookup takes a couple of cycles.

Still, virtual methods are the fastest kind of dynamic dispatch available in C#/on the CLR. Much faster than delegates and reflection.

Answer (score 4):

There are many questions of this sort. Are static methods faster/slower? Are virtual functions faster/slower? Is i++ faster/slower than ++i? Is for(;;) faster/slower than while(true)?

It is worthwhile getting hold of some software and [tuning it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773). That will give you a good sense of the kinds of things that actually affect software performance, in practice.

Then you will see that the answer to questions like that is (most of the time) that it is insignificant.

If I can generalize, the things that make software slow, in my experience, are the use of lines of code that look innocent but whose time consumption can be orders of magnitude larger than what might be imagined. Since they look innocent, they cannot reliably be found by looking at the code. Examples: Repeatedly allocating, initializing, and deallocating large data structures just to make sure they exist. Internationalizing strings that don't need to be. Notification-style programming that can turn a simple setting of a property into a massive cascade of method calls throughout a large data structure. Simple O(n^2) operations that would never have been a problem except that n got large. Thinking that (a < b) takes about the same length of time whether a and b are ints or big classes. This "time multiplication by looking innocent" has a compounding effect over multiple layers of abstraction, so large software tends to be riddled with it, in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is negligable in most cases, but static is more efficent.

The following steps are avoided in a static method call:

1. Checking that the object reference (this) is not null.
2. Finding the correct method on the virtual dispatch table.
3. Placing the object reference on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I find that many utility methods I write within a given class only need a few data members in the class, or none at all. In these cases, I tend to write those methods as (stand-alone) static methods, passing in directly the few data items that they need.

If they are particularly general and useful enough for other classes, I can make them public as well.