# How can global function exist in C#?

Tags: c#, function, global

How can global function exist in C# when everything is defined inside a class? I was reading the documentation of [OpCodes.Call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.call.aspx) at MSDN, and was surprised to see the following wordings,

> The metadata token carries sufficient information to determine whether the call is to a static method, an instance method, a virtual method, **or a global function.**

Global function? Does it exist in C#? (It definitely doesn't refer to `static` method, as it's explicitly listed along with global function).

Comment: OpCodes.Call is not specific to C# but to the CLR

Comment: If we told you we'd have to kill you. ;) Seriously, globals are bad - do not seek to implement them.

Comment: Why are global functions / methods bad by definition?

Comment: @Dennis http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151768/are-global-static-classes-and-methods-bad

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't have global functions in C#, it's just not part of the language.  You have to use a static method on some class of your choosing to get similar functionality.

However C# is not the only language that uses the CLR.  One can write Managed C++, which can have global functions.

Comment: But I've heard and read somewhere that when you write Managed C++ (or C++/CLI), all the global functions are pushed into a static class, generated by the compiler. In effect, there is no notion of global functions.

Comment: That may happen under the covers, I'm not sure.  If you find the link, please post it.  There are still other languages... I haven't taken a complete survey.

Comment: @Nawaz: That's an implementation detail that is not germane to this discussion. The salient point that point is that `System.Reflection.Emit` pertains to IL, not to C# or Managed C++ or any other language that is compiled into IL and sits on top of the .NET Framework. It doesn't matter if there are or aren't global functions in Managed C++, or how they are implemented. What matters, is that in virtual or real machines that interpret IL, there is a notion of global functions and `System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Call` can be used to emit an IL opcode that can invoke a global function.

Answer (score 14):

At the Build 2014 conference it was announced that from Roslyn onwards, you can import static methods from types by the `using TypeName;` directive, so that instead of having to use `System.Math.Min(...)` you can do:

```
using System.Math;
...
var z = Min(x,y);
```

---

Note: by the time of release this became:

```
using static System.Math;
```

Comment: Though in the sense of the original question, this is still not a global function; it's syntactic shorthand that saves you from typing "System.Math.Min" or "Math.Min". As far as the runtime it's still just a static function on the class "System.Math"

Answer (score 7):

Because `System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Call` isn't about C#. It's about emitting IL opcodes. In IL, there are features that are not available in C#. Global functions is one of those features.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation you are referring to is for .net. C# does not cater for global functions but .net does.

Comment: How exactly? Please be more generous in your answer. :-) (I'm new to .Net).

Comment: .net is a platform. The C# compiler exists on top of that platform, but .net was designed to serve more than C#. The C# designers elected not to cater for global functions in the design of that language, but other languages built on .net could elect to do so. In fact .net is full of features that are not exposed through individual languages.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just overwriting my previous answer...

Here is what each look like in IL DASM with their associated codes:

```
// Static Method
IL_0001:  call       void testapp.Form1::Test()

// Instance Method
IL_0001:  call       instance void testapp.Form1::Test()

// Virtual Method
IL_0001:  callvirt   instance void testapp.Form1::Test()

// Global Function
IL_0000:  call       void testapp.Test()
```

So to answer your question, there isn't a direct way to generate the metadata token in the last method for C#.  I had to create the last in C++.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that the thing is, that this is IL injection operation, but IL is *not* absolutely only about C#. In other words it's for support of the language that supports global functions.

Comment: @Nawaz: I believe this is about dynamic like languages, for example IronPython, F#(not very sure).  An interesting stuff can be found here on method dynamic generation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.modulebuilder.createglobalfunctions(VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 2):

C# does not support all features of MSIL. Global functions is one of them. VB.Net, F#, IronPython or some other language likley to use this and other features that are not generated by C# compiler.

Comment: They might, they might not. It doesn't matter. The key point is that IL supports them, and therefore virtual or real machines that interpret IL support them. It doesn't matter if other languages that are compiled into IL do, or if compilers for those languages translate those global functions into global functions in the compiled IL.