# rename a function in C#

Tags: c#, console, terminal, printf

is there a way in C# to rename System.Console.WriteLine
so that in my C#/console/visual studio program I could write

```
printf("hello");
//instead of 
System.Console.WriteLine("Hello");   //??
```

What would this be, a class?  a namespace?  Do I do this in the header or inside of main?

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: No, but you could just use C instead of C#.

Comment: Why you want to do that ? why not add a wrapper class to do this ?

Comment: Couldn't you just wrap `System.Console.WriteLine()` in a function of your own called `printf()`? Isn't this going to confuse people trying to maintain your code?

Comment: Why not just create a function with the relevant name you are looking to use. But please note that starting any function name with a lower case letter is not c# convention, so rather use Printf if you are going this route.

Comment: is there nothing like the functional `let myAdd = fun x y -> x + y` or `let printf = fun x -> System.Console.WriteLine("x")`  ?  your favorite succinct tutorial on C# wrappers?

Comment: Why not just be okay with `Console.WriteLine`?  There is no benefit to writing a method that simply wraps another public method.

Comment: In other news, look for a future post on thedailywtf.com!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can global function exist in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296106/how-can-global-function-exist-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your target looks strange and there is no way to do this in c#. Alternatively you can add a method in a class and use it.

```
private static void printf(string value)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Note: above method works only in the class which you write the above method.

Answer (score 7):

Write a wrapper:

```
public string printf(string theString)
{
  System.Console.WriteLine(theString);
}
```

Comment: <grin> ... you forgot the obligatory `// warning to future programmers: Prepare to be confused` :)

Comment: Clearly the OP needs this link: http://www.thc.org/root/phun/unmaintain.html  (and sorry, in advance, to any dev's morning/day I just wasted because they went off and read this.)

Answer (score 5):

You can use code snippets: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx
You can always write your own.

I think Visual Studio has a few by default, like writing `cw` and hitting `TAB` to get `System.Console.WriteLine`

**Edit**
Here is a list of the default VS code snippets: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat(v=vs.90).aspx

You can also use ReSharper to easily write your own, like this one I did for `dw` -> `Debug.WriteLine`

[image]

Comment: +1 assuming this question was to avoid keystrokes and not just to be sentimental about C.

Answer (score 2):

C# 6.0 Simplifies this by using static directives. Now instead of typing all of this: `System.Console.WriteLine(...)`, you could simply type: `WriteLine(...)`

[image]

```
using static System.Console;

namespace DemoApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteLine("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

More Info: [C# : How C# 6.0 Simplifies, Clarifies and Condenses Your Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879355.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your code in a function, for example

```
public void Printf(string message)
{
      System.Console.Writeline(message);
}
```

It is not recommended that you start your function with a lowercase letter (for example printf) as this is not a c# convention.

Answer (score 1):

First of all , do this is not a good practice.

But programatically this is achievable by wrting Wraps.

```
public string printf(string urstring)
{ 
System.Console.WriteLine(urstring);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get fancy you can do this:

```
static class DemoUtil
{
    public static void Print(this object self)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(self);
    }

    public static void Print(this string self)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(self);
    }
}
```

Then it would become:

```
"hello".Print();
12345.Print();
Math.Sin(0.345345).Print();
DateTime.Now.Print();
```

And so on. I don't recommend this for production code - but I do use this for my test code. I'm lazy.