# What this trick is?

Tags: c, macros

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PRINT(name) print ## name()

void printHE()
{
    printf("Hello");
}
void printWO()
{
    printf("World\n");
}


enum {
    HE,
    WO,
};

int main()
{
    PRINT(HE);
    PRINT(WO);
}
```

It works perfectly, but why?

What does `##` in `#define` mean?

And why `HE` didn't convert to `0` ?

Comment: Where is `PRINT` defined?

Comment: You don't show us the `#define` so we can only guess what you are doing. In the preprocessor `##` stands for concatenation.

Comment: **What ## in #define means?** ..Where is **##**???

Comment: Perhaps it's doing a [System.Console.WriteLine()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18639239/656243)  <grin>

Comment: Note that the `enum { HE, WO };` is a red herring — it has no effect or use in the code shown.

Comment: @trojanfoe `#define PRINT(name) print ## name` is not the defined?

Comment: @JensGustedt I think I post all my code

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I inserted the macro (and header); I missed the parentheses invoking the built function name in the first pass.

Comment: @LidongGuo: you definitely did not post all the code.  What you posted would not compile — there is no function `PRINT`.  You don't actually say what it means when "it works perfectly", but the presumption is that the program does compile and produces "HelloWorld" as output. For it to do that, you need a macro similar to the one I added which creates the function name and invokes it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh, I have a marco just the same as you add, so I think I post all my codes. sorry about this .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you're asking about `##` I am assuming that `PRINT` is defined as

```
#define PRINT(X) print##X()
```

The `##` is a token-pasting operator, it connects two tokens to its left and to its right together, producing a single token.

When you write `PRINT(HE)`, preprocessor converts that to `printHE()`, which is a regular function call.

> since HE is a enum, should HE translate to 0

That's a very good question! The translation does not happen, because preprocessor runs before `enum`s are interpreted, so the fact that `HE` and `WO` are `enum` members does not change anything.

Comment: I am confused about this : since `HE` is a enum, should `HE` translate  to `0` ?

Comment: @LidongGuo No, as mentioned the `enum` plays no part.  The pre-processor takes the term `print` and pastes it onto `HE` to produce `printHE`, which is the name of a function.

Comment: @LidongGuo That's a very good question, please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

It is the escape sequence in your expression. It concatenates the leftmost and the rightmost to produce the token.

**##** is token pasting operator

Answer (score 0):

In `#define PRINT(name) print ## name`

`##` is [token pasting operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09dwwt6y.aspx), used to "glue" tokens together

Answer (score 0):

On my computer, it doesn't work right. Print error like below:

two_sharp.c:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `PRINT'
two_sharp.c:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to`PRINT'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status