# When should types or members be declared static?

Tags: c#, oop

The `static` modifier means that the type cannot be instantiated or a member cannot be associated with an instance. But  whats the benefit of this restriction on instantiation and under what  use case scenario should types/members be declared static ?

Comment: I think my question is misunderstood. I know what static does. But when does it make sense to restrict instantiation ?

Comment: A bit of searching here would probably answer your question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227793/why-are-static-classes-used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169378/c-method-can-be-made-static-but-should-it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241339/when-to-use-static-classes-in-c

Comment: oh.. thanks , that didn't show up during writing the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But whats the benefit of this restriction on instantiation and under what use case scenario should types/members be declared static ?

For members, when you have state that belongs to the class (or should be shared among all instances of the class) or methods that don't depend on instance-level state.

For types, when you have a bag of methods that aren't dependent on instance-level state (for example, `System.Math`) including extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

Types are declared static to define, that no instances of this type can be created (and can only contain static data).

Methods are defined static in a non-static class when they do not reference the internal data of a class. This is sometimes important to know when reading or using code.

Comment: To continue, members should not be static unless there's a good reason for it. You should remember that there's a possibility that you might want to have two copies of your form, list etc. sometime in the future. And a lot of static fields encourages bad practices, with a lot of dependencies between everything. And if you are thinking about multithreading, you have to know what you are doing.. I try to make only "Contextbound" objects available through static properties, for example a config object.

Comment: @Onkelberg, do you include as a good reason that the method or member does not reference the state of the object? cause if you do, then since if this is not true, you can't make it static, that implies a if and only if rule that leaves no room for "reasons", no ?

Comment: You might want to modify your answer to say "reference" the internal data of a class.. .instead of "modify" ...

Answer (score 0):

Several benefits:

1. Uses less memory as object doesn't need to be instantiated to call a method
2. Allows global access to a property / member (although threading issues need to be considered)
3. Indicates to the caller that the method is an aspect of the class rather than the object instance which has implications with regards to OOP.

Answer (score 0):

Types should be declared as static when you want the compiler to inhibit the instantiation of instances of the type, and prevent the additional of any non-static (instance based) members.  All this does is guarantee that you won't inadvertently add a non-static member later.

Members of a non-static class should be declared as static *If and Only If* the member does not reference any instance-based state of the object, (directly, or indirectly through another non-static member). They cannot reference any non-static member of the type, but non-static members can reference them.

Comment: -1 This explains the how, but not the why.  The OP wanted the why.

Answer (score 0):

I go by the following principles.

Declare static if:

- You **need** static access (beware of this though since it creates Very hard dependencies), i usually only allow static access for Inversion of Control accessors and simple functionality helpers (such as System.Math)
- You absolutely doesn't want your class to be instantiated and should only exist as one single instance (singleton) such as in the above case of a helper or IoC container

Don't declare static if:

- There is any chance of concurrency issues. Private readonly value -instances can only be read and are as such practically readonly so these are fine as static constant-a-like members but otherwise be wary.
- There exists dependencies outside the class, ie something else uses the member or the member uses something else outside the type. This makes testing  a pain.

So mainly, increase cohesion decrease coupling, otherwise you´re fine using static instances.

Comment: I would turn that logic on its head: `static` (on members) should be the default option. Only make it an instance when it *cannot* be static, i.e. when it logically belongs to the object’s state.

Comment: I agree with your statement that only members belonging to the state should be instanced but generally things that doesn't belong to the objects state should be in some way injected to avoid depending on external state, what do you think?