# Cannot create an instance of the static class 'MailServer'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use the method 'SendSoporteMail' to send an email. This method is in another project called 'BCR.System', in the SMTSenderSimple.cs controller within the static MailServer class.

BCR.System > Comunication > SmtpSenderSimple.cs

In my current project I wrote this, but is giving me the title's error.

```
        var MailController = new BCR.System.Communication.MailServer();
        MailController.SendSoporteMail("mailto@gmail.com", "Invitation", Body );
```

Comment: Yeah, you can't create instances of static classes (that's kind of the point of them). Perhaps you want `BCR.System.Communication.MailServer.SendSoporteMail`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why we cannot create the Instance of the Static Class in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444155/why-we-cannot-create-the-instance-of-the-static-class-in-net)

Comment: Thank you! , I struggle with static classes and methods.