# Swagger UI Web Api documentation Present enums as strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Is there a way to display all enums as their string value in swagger instead of their int value?

I want to be able to submit POST actions and put enums according to their string value without having to look at the enum every time.

I tried `DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings` but the server then receives strings instead of the enum value which is not what we're looking for.

Has anyone solved this?

Edit:

```
public class Letter 
{
    [Required]
    public string Content {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [EnumDataType(typeof(Priority))]
    public Priority Priority {get; set;}
}


public class LettersController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult SendLetter(Letter letter)
    {
        // Validation not passing when using DescribeEnumsAsStrings
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest("Not valid")

        ..
    }

    // In the documentation for this request I want to see the string values of the enum before submitting: Low, Medium, High. Instead of 0, 1, 2
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetByPriority (Priority priority)
    {

    }
}


public enum Priority
{
    Low, 
    Medium,
    High
}
```

Comment: Do you want the schema to describe the value as a string but then post an integer to the server? JSON.net will handle both values fine, so is the integer only version a definite requirement? I don't think Swagger supports a enum type with both the string and integer value.

Comment: Your expected behavior is unclear, can you better explain what you want Swagger UI to display and what you want to POST/PUT to your Web API with examples?

Comment: Moreover, if I have GET methods that take enum in the url, I want the scheme to describe it as strings in the drop down list of suggested values

Comment: Why does integer validation fail? The type should be an enum in the model and the json media formatter would correctly handle either a string or int. If you update the question with an example it would help us understand why the validation is failing.

Comment: If it's a flags enum, the it has to be numeric, unless you have enum values defined for every possible combination of flags.  It's nuts that swagger doesn't display BOTH the name and value for each enum, and instead displays number alone (useless) or names alone (again, useless for flags which must be specified as numbers).

Answer (score 293):

## For ASP.NET Core 3 with the Microsoft JSON library (System.Text.Json)

In Startup.cs/ConfigureServices():

```
services
    .AddControllersWithViews(...) // or AddControllers() in a Web API
    .AddJsonOptions(options => 
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
```

## For ASP.NET Core 3 with the Json.NET (Newtonsoft.Json) library

Install the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft` package.

In Startup.cs/ConfigureServices():

```
services
    .AddControllersWithViews(...)
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => 
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter()));
// order is vital, this *must* be called *after* AddNewtonsoftJson()
services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();
```

## For ASP.NET Core 2

In Startup.cs/ConfigureServices():

```
services
    .AddMvc(...)
    .AddJsonOptions(options => 
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter()));
```

## Pre-ASP.NET Core

```cs
httpConfiguration
    .EnableSwagger(c => 
        {
            c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
        });
```

Comment: Problem of using   options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter())) is that your changing the json for all your methods, not only for Sawshbuckle.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for Azure Functions v2 and/or v3?

Comment: @DanFriedman Considering Swashbuckle doesn't work with Azure Functions at all, you're out of luck.

Comment: @IanKemp There is third party support with the `AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle` package but like @DanFriedman I cannot get the enum-to-string working as expected

Comment: If you're configuring for ASP.NET Core 3 with Newtonsoft, the `AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport()` extension method is available from NuGet package`Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft`. Read more here: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#systemtextjson-stj-vs-newtonsoft

Comment: `AddNewtonsoftJson` accepts `IMvcBuilder`. It won't work with `IServiceCollection`. Please fix your code for For ASP.NET Core 3 with the Json.NET (Newtonsoft.Json) library.

Comment: and for NET 6 minimal API ?

Comment: minimal api is same if you add controllers like the comment about web api. `builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));`

Answer (score 277):

### Enable globally

From [the docs](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/e2fa027dfb9652304e13d68f9ca06a2be0b4296f/README.md#describeallenumsasstrings):

```
httpConfiguration
    .EnableSwagger(c => 
        {
            c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "A title for your API");
            
            c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings(); // this will do the trick
        });
```

### Enum/string conversion on particular property

Also, if you want this behavior only on a particular type and property, use the StringEnumConverter:

```
public class Letter 
{
    [Required]
    public string Content {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [EnumDataType(typeof(Priority))]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public Priority Priority {get; set;}
}
```

#### If you're using Newtonsoft and Swashbuckle v5.0.0 or higher

You'll also need this package:

```
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft
```

And this in your startup:

```
services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport(); // explicit opt-in - needs to be placed after AddSwaggerGen()
```

There's docs here: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#systemtextjson-stj-vs-newtonsoft

Comment: this doesn't work for me.[EnumDataType(typeof(Priority))]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]

Comment: @NH. yes,  i used newtonsoft.json

Comment: @Lineker, post your error as a new question, following this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thx! I think I might just leave your comment in the source too #thiswilldothetrick

Comment: Hmm why is EnumDataType required? Is there a way to make it smart enough to auto detect

Comment: if you use the line with "#thiswilldothetrick", you dont need the StringEnumConverterAttribute. The Attibutes are only required when you want this feature in a specific Property. 

Also, I dont remember what the EnumDataTypeAttribute does, but perphaps you dont need it.

Comment: ASP.NET Core documentation: [Customize Schema for Enum Types](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#customize-schema-for-enum-types)

Comment: worked instantly for me. How do I make them lower case now?

Comment: I think the Lowercase its achieved with the Json converter/Newtonsoft, but i am not sure.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, sppotedmahn's link shows how to do it: c.DescribeStringEnumsInCamelCase();

Comment: `DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings` worked for object properties and even query parameters on controller actions. However, using `EnumDataTypeAttribute` and `JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))` did not work for me.

Comment: This solution omits **important** step of registering StringEnumConverter as a converter in AddNewtonsoftJson section of AddMvc. See example in @Roman Starkov answer below.

Comment: in core2.0 it displays the keys, but not the values as expected.
also data member description not works see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64764537/net-core-2-0-swagger-enum-display

Comment: `c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();` is deprecated in Swagger 5.6.0.

Comment: Where can I get the `httpConfiguration` object?

Comment: @computercarguy I had to use `c.UseInlineDefinitionsForEnums();` instead.

Comment: Downvoting because this answer is obsolete as pointed out above

Answer (score 55):

So I think I have a similar problem. I'm looking for swagger to generate enums along with the int -> string mapping. The API must accept the int. The swagger-ui matters less, what I really want is code generation with a "real" enum on the other side (android apps using retrofit in this case).

So from my research this ultimately seems to be a limit of the OpenAPI specification which Swagger uses. It's not possible to specify names and numbers for enums.

The best issue I've found to follow is https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/681 which looks like a "maybe soon" but then Swagger would have to be updated, and in my case Swashbuckle as well.

For now my workaround has been to implement a document filter that looks for enums and populates the relevant description with the contents of the enum.

```
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.DocumentFilter<SwaggerAddEnumDescriptions>();

                    //disable this
                    //c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings()
```

SwaggerAddEnumDescriptions.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using Swashbuckle.Swagger;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SwaggerAddEnumDescriptions : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, IApiExplorer apiExplorer)
    {
        // add enum descriptions to result models
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Schema> schemaDictionaryItem in swaggerDoc.definitions)
        {
            Schema schema = schemaDictionaryItem.Value;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Schema> propertyDictionaryItem in schema.properties)
            {
                Schema property = propertyDictionaryItem.Value;
                IList<object> propertyEnums = property.@enum;
                if (propertyEnums != null && propertyEnums.Count > 0)
                {
                    property.description += DescribeEnum(propertyEnums);
                }
            }
        }

        // add enum descriptions to input parameters
        if (swaggerDoc.paths.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (PathItem pathItem in swaggerDoc.paths.Values)
            {
                DescribeEnumParameters(pathItem.parameters);

                // head, patch, options, delete left out
                List<Operation> possibleParameterisedOperations = new List<Operation> { pathItem.get, pathItem.post, pathItem.put };
                possibleParameterisedOperations.FindAll(x => x != null).ForEach(x => DescribeEnumParameters(x.parameters));
            }
        }
    }

    private void DescribeEnumParameters(IList<Parameter> parameters)
    {
        if (parameters != null)
        {
            foreach (Parameter param in parameters)
            {
                IList<object> paramEnums = param.@enum;
                if (paramEnums != null && paramEnums.Count > 0)
                {
                    param.description += DescribeEnum(paramEnums);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private string DescribeEnum(IList<object> enums)
    {
        List<string> enumDescriptions = new List<string>();
        foreach (object enumOption in enums)
        {
            enumDescriptions.Add(string.Format("{0} = {1}", (int)enumOption, Enum.GetName(enumOption.GetType(), enumOption)));
        }
        return string.Join(", ", enumDescriptions.ToArray());
    }

}
```

This results in something like the following on your swagger-ui so at least you can "see what you're doing":
[image]

Comment: +1 I was looking to add descriptions to enums (just to 'describe enum'), never thought of this. I already have misc filters in place, but was looking for something more 'organic', but there's no support. Well then, filters all the way :)

Comment: Thanks! I used this in my project, but modified it to work with .NET Core. I added my implementation as an answer.

Answer (score 50):

#### ASP.NET Core 3.1

To generate enums as strings using Newtonsoft JSON you must explicitly add Newtonsoft support by adding `AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport()` as follows:

```
services.AddMvc()
    ...
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(opts =>
    {
        opts.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
    });


services.AddSwaggerGen(...);
services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport(); //
```

This is available via a new package, `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft`. It looks like everything else works fine without this package apart from enum converter support.

Comment: It helps to setup this convention globally, but if you need to apply this only to certain types of enums, you will need to carefully read this [issue](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1459). 
TL; DR:
It's not possible to apply new StringEnumConverter() to property only, but you can apply it to the whole enum type.

Comment: I suppose if we're talking of gotchas, it's also not possible to use a completely custom converter. Swagger doesn't run the enum values through the custom converter; it simply recognizes `StringEnumConverter` as a special case.

Comment: What is the recommended solution in .net 5?

Answer (score 44):

**.NET CORE 3.1 and SWAGGER 5**

if you need a simple solution to **selectively** make enums passed as strings:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;


[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
public enum MyEnum
{
    A, B
}
```

Note, we use `System.Text.Json.Serialization` namespace, not the `Newtonsoft.Json`!

Comment: This one works showing the proper values, and also works when converting the values back to the enum. Note that you need to add the NuGet package `System.Text.Json`.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! As I have to use string for just single enum, and `DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings` will convert all enums to the string.

Comment: Thanks for this simple solution. I'm using .NET Core 3.1 and Swagger 5.5.

didn't need to use DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings . 

Just set [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))] on enum. 

EX:
System.Text.Json.Serialization;


[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public enum Category
    {
        Autos,
        Electronics,
        Furniture,
        House,
        Pets,
        Miscellaneous
    }

Answer (score 32):

#### ASP.NET Core 6 / ASP.NET Core 7

In your program.cs:

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
});
```

Please also note:

[DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings is obsolete](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1269)

Comment: I'm not sure why this doesn't have more upvotes. It did exactly what I was looking for. POST/GET json serialization/deserialization everywhere in my code my Enum values were treated as strings perfectly as expected.

Answer (score 27):

My variant for enum stings with values:

[image]

Configure Services:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "web server api", Version = "v1" });
                c.SchemaFilter<EnumSchemaFilter>();
            });
```

Filter:

```
public class EnumSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiSchema model, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            if (context.Type.IsEnum)
            {
                model.Enum.Clear();
                Enum.GetNames(context.Type)
                    .ToList()
                    .ForEach(name => model.Enum.Add(new OpenApiString($"{Convert.ToInt64(Enum.Parse(context.Type, name))} - {name}")));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this works only on Core3.0, filter not exist in Core2

Comment: It works in .Net 5. DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings (deprecated) and AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport is not working in .Net 5.

Comment: Only thing that worked for me for what I wanted.

Comment: I spent three days looking for this. Tried stuff that involved other libraries, but didn't give me what I needed. Here you go showing me how to do it in 4 lines of code. Thanks!

Comment: This will render your swagger requests unusable as it will overwrite your int representation of value. Use with caution.

Comment: @OhWelp You are absolutely right! Do you know how this could be split? To return this string in the schema for convenience (to know the string behind each number), but keep the mock data for the requests with just a number as it is by default?

Comment: I found a solution: `model.Example = new OpenApiInteger(Convert.ToInt32(Enum.Parse(context.Type, names.First())));` - names is the `Enum.GetNames(context.Type).ToList()`

Answer (score 26):

I wanted to use rory_za's answer in a .NET Core application, but I had to modify it a bit to make it work. Here is the implementation I came up with for .NET Core.

I also changed it so it doesn't assume the underlying type is `int`, and use new lines between the values for easier reading.

```
/// <summary>
/// Add enum value descriptions to Swagger
/// </summary>
public class EnumDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter {
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context) {
        // add enum descriptions to result models
        foreach (var schemaDictionaryItem in swaggerDoc.Definitions) {
            var schema = schemaDictionaryItem.Value;
            foreach (var propertyDictionaryItem in schema.Properties) {
                var property = propertyDictionaryItem.Value;
                var propertyEnums = property.Enum;
                if (propertyEnums != null && propertyEnums.Count > 0) {
                    property.Description += DescribeEnum(propertyEnums);
                }
            }
        }

        if (swaggerDoc.Paths.Count <= 0) return;

        // add enum descriptions to input parameters
        foreach (var pathItem in swaggerDoc.Paths.Values) {
            DescribeEnumParameters(pathItem.Parameters);

            // head, patch, options, delete left out
            var possibleParameterisedOperations = new List<Operation> {pathItem.Get, pathItem.Post, pathItem.Put};
            possibleParameterisedOperations.FindAll(x => x != null)
                .ForEach(x => DescribeEnumParameters(x.Parameters));
        }
    }

    private static void DescribeEnumParameters(IList<IParameter> parameters) {
        if (parameters == null) return;

        foreach (var param in parameters) {
            if (param is NonBodyParameter nbParam && nbParam.Enum?.Any() == true) {
                param.Description += DescribeEnum(nbParam.Enum);
            } else if (param.Extensions.ContainsKey("enum") && param.Extensions["enum"] is IList<object> paramEnums &&
                paramEnums.Count > 0) {
                param.Description += DescribeEnum(paramEnums);
            }
        }
    }

    private static string DescribeEnum(IEnumerable<object> enums) {
        var enumDescriptions = new List<string>();
        Type type = null;
        foreach (var enumOption in enums) {
            if (type == null) type = enumOption.GetType();
            enumDescriptions.Add($"{Convert.ChangeType(enumOption, type.GetEnumUnderlyingType())} = {Enum.GetName(type, enumOption)}");
        }

        return $"{Environment.NewLine}{string.Join(Environment.NewLine, enumDescriptions)}";
    }
}
```

Then add this to your `ConfigureServices` method in Startup.cs:

```
c.DocumentFilter<EnumDocumentFilter>();
```

Comment: Possible to remove the Enum: Array [ 6 ] which appears below ?

Comment: Great solution, but the extensions in `DescribeEnumParameters` were empty in my project. I had to cast the `param` to `NonBodyParameter` and check the enum there: `if (param is NonBodyParameter nbParam && nbParam.Enum?.Any() == true)
                {
                    param.Description += DescribeEnum(nbParam.Enum);
                }`

Comment: On my project Extensions is empty too, used the @Rabban solution.

Comment: @Rabban I updated my code to include that. Can you just verify I put it in the right place? I didn't have this issue. Maybe a newer version changed things.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Confirmed and approved ;)

Comment: Solution works great, thanks so much. Any reason why DescribeEnumParameters is static?

Comment: @Rocklan Because it can be :) And static methods are [slightly more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2142062/1202807) than ones that aren't.

Comment: what value should i put above each value? currently i get error : 
-  $exception {"Type provided must be an Enum.\r\nParameter name: enumType"} System.ArgumentException

Answer (score 25):

if anyone is interested i have modified the code to work with

**.NET CORE 3** and **Swagger V5**

```
    public class SwaggerAddEnumDescriptions : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        // add enum descriptions to result models
        foreach (var property in swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Where(x => x.Value?.Enum?.Count > 0))
        {
            IList<IOpenApiAny> propertyEnums = property.Value.Enum;
            if (propertyEnums != null && propertyEnums.Count > 0)
            {
                property.Value.Description += DescribeEnum(propertyEnums, property.Key);
            }
        }

        // add enum descriptions to input parameters
        foreach (var pathItem in swaggerDoc.Paths.Values)
        {
            DescribeEnumParameters(pathItem.Operations, swaggerDoc);
        }
    }

    private void DescribeEnumParameters(IDictionary<OperationType, OpenApiOperation> operations, OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc)
    {
        if (operations != null)
        {
            foreach (var oper in operations)
            {
                foreach (var param in oper.Value.Parameters)
                {
                    var paramEnum = swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == param.Name);
                    if (paramEnum.Value != null)
                    {
                        param.Description += DescribeEnum(paramEnum.Value.Enum, paramEnum.Key);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private Type GetEnumTypeByName(string enumTypeName)
    {
        return AppDomain.CurrentDomain
            .GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == enumTypeName);
    }

    private string DescribeEnum(IList<IOpenApiAny> enums, string proprtyTypeName)
    {
        List<string> enumDescriptions = new List<string>();
        var enumType = GetEnumTypeByName(proprtyTypeName);
        if (enumType == null)
            return null;

        foreach (IOpenApiAny enumOption in enums)
        {
            if (enumOption is OpenApiString @string)
            {
                string enumString = @string.Value;

                enumDescriptions.Add(string.Format("{0} = {1}", (int)Enum.Parse(enumType, enumString), enumString));
            }
            else if (enumOption is OpenApiInteger integer)
            {
                int enumInt = integer.Value;

                enumDescriptions.Add(string.Format("{0} = {1}", enumInt, Enum.GetName(enumType, enumInt)));
            }
        }

        return string.Join(", ", enumDescriptions.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works when the parameter type is *exactly* enum... not nullable enum, collection of enums etc. Check my answer for those cases.

Comment: When I run this code I find that enumOption is of type OpenApiString in DescribeEnum

Comment: Your solution is working, only if I change `GetEnumTypeByName` FirstOfDefaultCondition to this `.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FullName == enumTypeName || x.Name == enumTypeName);`

Comment: Weirdly - for my enums:

swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Where(x => x.Value?.Enum?.Count > 0).  

Enum is actually an empty array...

Answer (score 21):

This is not possible with standard OpenAPI. Enums are described only with their string values.

Fortunately you can do it with some non-standard extensions that are utilized by your client generator.

NSwag supports `x-enumNames`

AutoRest supports `x-ms-enum`.

Openapi-generator supports `x-enum-varnames`

Other generators might support one of these extensions or have their own.

To generate `x-enumNames` for NSwag create the following schema filter:

```
public class EnumSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.Type.IsEnum)
        {
            var array = new OpenApiArray();
            array.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(context.Type).Select(n => new OpenApiString(n)));
            // NSwag
            schema.Extensions.Add("x-enumNames", array);
            // Openapi-generator
            schema.Extensions.Add("x-enum-varnames", array);
        }
    }
}
```

And register it as:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SchemaFilter<EnumSchemaFilter>();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what helped me in my net5 project

Comment: Net 6 minimal API not supports Filters

Comment: Hmm. I have the x-enumNames on the server and openapi spec, but NSwag ignores them on client generation.

Answer (score 16):

**With asp.net core 3**

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
         services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
             options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
```

But it seems that Swashbuckle Version 5.0.0-rc4 is not ready to support that. So we need to use an option(deprecated) in the Swashbuckle config file until it supports and reflects it like Newtonsoft library.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{ 
      services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
      {
            c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
```

The difference between this answer and other answers is using only the Microsoft JSON library instead of Newtonsoft.

Comment: Hey @Bashir, is there a swachbuckle issue to keep track of the lack of that support?

Comment: Hi @bernard-vander-beken, I did not report that but I assume there is. It is good if we can find it and add it to this post for a later updates.

Comment: Looks like its here: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1269

Answer (score 11):

I have found nice workaround Here:

@PauloVetor - solved it using ShemaFilter like this:

```
public class EnumSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema model, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.Type.IsEnum)
        {
            model.Enum.Clear();
            Enum.GetNames(context.Type)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(n =>
                {
                    model.Enum.Add(new OpenApiString(n)); 
                    model.Type = "string";
                    model.Format = null;
                });
        }
    }
}
```

And in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SchemaFilter<EnumSchemaFilter>();
}
```

**Note**: use this solution when enums are generated as ints into json (`StringEnumConverter` is not used or cannot be used). Swagger will show enum names, and will pass the string value into the API, and luckily ASP.NET Core can handle enum values as ints and also as strings, where the string value has to be case-insentitive enum name (e.g. for enum `Priority.Low`, ASP.NET Core accepts string values `Low`, `low`, `lOw`, etc).

Comment: You should also ensure that you update the `model.Format` to `"string"` as it will generally be `"int32"`.

Comment: I had to update the model.Type to "string" for the same reason Isuarez mentioned.

Comment: Bravo. While I am forced to continue using Newtonsoft.Json, I didn't necessarily need that to be recognized in the API documentation generation, I just needed enums to be represented as strings. Barring a more complicated scenario (like custom newtonsoft enum names), surprisingly this just worked.

Comment: few tweaks to make it work: 1- `model.Format = null;`  2- `model.Type = "string";`

Comment: and for NET 6 minimal api ?

Answer (score 10):

I have modified Hosam Rehani's answer to work with nullable enums and with collection of enums also. The previous answer also works only if a property is named exactly like it's type. All these problems are addressed in the code below.

It works with .net core 3.x and swagger 5.x.

it could be more efficient by not searching for the enum type twice in some cases.

```
class SwaggerAddEnumDescriptions : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        // add enum descriptions to result models
        foreach (var property in swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Where(x => x.Value?.Enum?.Count > 0))
        {
            IList<IOpenApiAny> propertyEnums = property.Value.Enum;
            if (propertyEnums != null && propertyEnums.Count > 0)
            {
                property.Value.Description += DescribeEnum(propertyEnums, property.Key);
            }
        }

        // add enum descriptions to input parameters
        foreach (var pathItem in swaggerDoc.Paths)
        {
            DescribeEnumParameters(pathItem.Value.Operations, swaggerDoc, context.ApiDescriptions, pathItem.Key);
        }
    }

    private void DescribeEnumParameters(IDictionary<OperationType, OpenApiOperation> operations, OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, IEnumerable<ApiDescription> apiDescriptions, string path)
    {
        path = path.Trim('/');
        if (operations != null)
        {
            var pathDescriptions = apiDescriptions.Where(a => a.RelativePath == path);
            foreach (var oper in operations)
            {
                var operationDescription = pathDescriptions.FirstOrDefault(a => a.HttpMethod.Equals(oper.Key.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
                foreach (var param in oper.Value.Parameters)
                {
                    var parameterDescription = operationDescription.ParameterDescriptions.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == param.Name);
                    if (parameterDescription != null && TryGetEnumType(parameterDescription.Type, out Type enumType))
                    {
                        var paramEnum = swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == enumType.Name);
                        if (paramEnum.Value != null)
                        {
                            param.Description += DescribeEnum(paramEnum.Value.Enum, paramEnum.Key);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    bool TryGetEnumType(Type type, out Type enumType)
    {
        if (type.IsEnum)
        {
            enumType = type;
            return true;
        }
        else if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
        {
            var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
            if (underlyingType != null && underlyingType.IsEnum == true)
            {
                enumType = underlyingType;
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Type underlyingType = GetTypeIEnumerableType(type);
            if (underlyingType != null && underlyingType.IsEnum)
            {
                enumType = underlyingType;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                var interfaces = type.GetInterfaces();
                foreach (var interfaceType in interfaces)
                {
                    underlyingType = GetTypeIEnumerableType(interfaceType);
                    if (underlyingType != null && underlyingType.IsEnum)
                    {
                        enumType = underlyingType;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        enumType = null;
        return false;
    }

    Type GetTypeIEnumerableType(Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
        {
            var underlyingType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            if (underlyingType.IsEnum)
            {
                return underlyingType;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private Type GetEnumTypeByName(string enumTypeName)
    {
        return AppDomain.CurrentDomain
            .GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == enumTypeName);
    }

    private string DescribeEnum(IList<IOpenApiAny> enums, string proprtyTypeName)
    {
        List<string> enumDescriptions = new List<string>();
        var enumType = GetEnumTypeByName(proprtyTypeName);
        if (enumType == null)
            return null;

        foreach (OpenApiInteger enumOption in enums)
        {
            int enumInt = enumOption.Value;

            enumDescriptions.Add(string.Format("{0} = {1}", enumInt, Enum.GetName(enumType, enumInt)));
        }

        return string.Join(", ", enumDescriptions.ToArray());
    }
}
```

to use the filter add `c.DocumentFilter<SwaggerAddEnumDescriptions>();` to swagger configuration in `Startup.cs`.

Answer (score 10):

**For .NET core 5**
it is same as .NET core 3.1
which is to add

```
   options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
```

Example:

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
    var builder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(builder.Build()));
 }).AddJsonOptions(options =>
 {
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
 });
```

Comment: In .NET core 5, the `.Converters.Add(..)` approach does not work for me, while the `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` without having any other settings. Any idea why?

Answer (score 9):

Simple Solution. It works for me.

```
   using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
    
    
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public enum Priority
    {
        Low, 
        Medium,
        High
    }
```

Comment: Is there any global option instead of decorating POCOs with Json converter attributes? How does it appear in swagger doc? Does it generate Enum on the client side code generation as well?

Comment: @MaulikModi In Swagger doc, it changes the type to string and provides a list of available values.

Comment: This was actually what worked with NSwagStudio export

Answer (score 7):

To display the enums as strings in swagger, please configure the JsonStringEnumConverter by adding the following line in ConfigureServices :

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
```

If you want to display the enums as strings and int values, you could try to create an EnumSchemaFilter to change the schema, as below:

```
public class EnumSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema model, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.Type.IsEnum)
        {
            model.Enum.Clear();
            Enum.GetNames(context.Type)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(name => model.Enum.Add(new OpenApiString($"{Convert.ToInt64(Enum.Parse(context.Type, name))} = {name}")));
        }
    }
}
```

Configure the SwaggerGen to use the above SchemaFilter :

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "ToDo API",
                Description = "A simple example ASP.NET Core Web API",
                TermsOfService = new Uri("https://example.com/terms"),
                Contact = new OpenApiContact
                {
                    Name = "Shayne Boyer",
                    Email = string.Empty,
                    Url = new Uri("https://twitter.com/spboyer"),
                },
                License = new OpenApiLicense
                {
                    Name = "Use under LICX",
                    Url = new Uri("https://example.com/license"),
                }
            });
              
            c.SchemaFilter<EnumSchemaFilter>();
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, this works fine and is exactly what i was looking for. But it rises a new issue. The example JSON value of the request in the Swagger UI, shows the required enum as defined in the EnumSchemaFilter which results in: { ...."language": "en(1)",...}. The "Try it out" and then 'execute' button won't work whit this adaption. Any improvement advises for this issue?

Comment: valid for NET 6 minimal api ?

Answer (score 5):

After searching for answers here, I found the partial solution for the issue with displaying enums in the Schema as `[SomeEnumString = 0, AnotherEnumString = 1]`, but all of the answers related to this are only **partially correct** as **@OhWelp** mentioned in one of the comments.

Here's the full solution for .NET core (2, 3, currently working on 6):

```
    public class EnumSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiSchema model, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            if (context.Type.IsEnum)
            {
                model.Enum.Clear();

                var names = Enum.GetNames(context.Type).ToList();

                names.ForEach(name => model.Enum.Add(new OpenApiString($"{GetEnumIntegerValue(name, context)} = {name}")));


                 // the missing piece that will make sure that the new schema will not replace the mock value with a wrong value 
                // this is the default behavior - the first possible enum value as a default "example" value
                model.Example = new OpenApiInteger(GetEnumIntegerValue(names.First(), context));
            }
        }

        private int GetEnumIntegerValue(string name, SchemaFilterContext context) => Convert.ToInt32(Enum.Parse(context.Type, name));
    }
```

And in the startup/program:

```
    services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SchemaFilter<EnumSchemaFilter>();
        });
```

EDIT: Refactored the code a bit, if you want to see the original version which is more similar to the rest of the answers please, check the chronology of edits.

Answer (score 4):

> in .net core 3.1 & swagger 5.0.0 :

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Any;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;

namespace WebFramework.Swagger
{
    public class EnumSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            if (context.Type.IsEnum)
            {
                var enumValues = schema.Enum.ToArray();
                var i = 0;
                schema.Enum.Clear();
                foreach (var n in Enum.GetNames(context.Type).ToList())
                {
                    schema.Enum.Add(new OpenApiString(n + $" = {((OpenApiPrimitive<int>)enumValues[i]).Value}"));
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

> and in Startup.cs :

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                #region  EnumDesc
                options.SchemaFilter<EnumSchemaFilter>();
                #endregion
            });
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Down side of this is, that when executing a request, instead of passing only int representation (like 2 for example) of an enum value the API will get the full description as a value (like LogicError = 3), which will fail as a bad request since it is not valid value for the enum.

Comment: ApiResult is a response class .
validation of enum in imput parameter is another discuese
in .core you can use IValidatableObject and implementation : public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) 
on object

Answer (score 4):

**If you are using newtonsof.json then use this**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;


[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum MyEnum
{
    A, B
}
```

**If you are using System.Text.Json.Serialization**

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;


[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
public enum MyEnum
{
    A, B
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Go to Program.cs and put the below code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json;
using MvcJsonOptions = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonOptions;

.....

builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(o => o.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
builder.Services.Configure<MvcJsonOptions>(o => o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
```

Answer (score 4):

I got it **working for .NET 6 Web API** using the following code based from the other answers here:

1 - Create a DocumentFilter

```
/// <summary>
/// Add enum value descriptions to Swagger
/// </summary>
public class SwaggerEnumDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        // add enum descriptions to result models
        foreach (var property in swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas)
        {
            var propertyEnums = property.Value.Enum;
            if (propertyEnums is { Count: > 0 })
            {
                property.Value.Description += DescribeEnum(propertyEnums, property.Key);
            }
        }

        if (swaggerDoc.Paths.Count <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        // add enum descriptions to input parameters
        foreach (var pathItem in swaggerDoc.Paths.Values)
        {
            DescribeEnumParameters(pathItem.Parameters);

            var affectedOperations = new List<OperationType> { OperationType.Get, OperationType.Post, OperationType.Put, OperationType.Patch };

            foreach (var operation in pathItem.Operations)
            {
                if (affectedOperations.Contains(operation.Key))
                {
                    DescribeEnumParameters(operation.Value.Parameters);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void DescribeEnumParameters(IList<OpenApiParameter> parameters)
    {
        if (parameters == null) return;

        foreach (var param in parameters)
        {
            if (param.Schema.Reference != null)
            {
                var enumType = GetEnumTypeByName(param.Schema.Reference.Id);
                var names = Enum.GetNames(enumType).ToList();

                param.Description += string.Join(", ", names.Select(name => $"{Convert.ToInt32(Enum.Parse(enumType, name))} - {name}").ToList());
            }
        }
    }

    private static Type GetEnumTypeByName(string enumTypeName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(enumTypeName))
        {
            return null;
        }

        try
        {
            return AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                            .GetAssemblies()
                            .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                            .Single(x => x.FullName != null
                                      && x.Name == enumTypeName);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            throw new Exception($"SwaggerDoc: Can not find a unique Enum for specified typeName '{enumTypeName}'. Please provide a more unique enum name.");
        }
    }

    private static string DescribeEnum(IEnumerable<IOpenApiAny> enums, string propertyTypeName)
    {
        var enumType = GetEnumTypeByName(propertyTypeName);

        if (enumType == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var parsedEnums = new List<OpenApiInteger>();
        foreach (var @enum in enums)
        {
            if (@enum is OpenApiInteger enumInt)
            {
                parsedEnums.Add(enumInt);
            }
        }

        return string.Join(", ", parsedEnums.Select(x => $"{x.Value} - {Enum.GetName(enumType, x.Value)}"));
    }

}
```

2 - Add it to your Program.cs file

```
   services.AddSwaggerGen(config =>
        {

            config.DocumentFilter<SwaggerEnumDocumentFilter>();

        })
```

[image: Schema Result]

[image: Parameter]

Answer (score 3):

I just did this and it works fine!

Startup.cs

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
  c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
});
```

Model.cs

```
public enum ColumnType {
  DATE = 0
}
```

swagger.json

```
type: {
  enum: ["DATE"],
  type: "string"
}
```

I hope this helps you how it helped me!

Comment: `DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings` is deprecated

Comment: This doesn't exist. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

write code inside Startup.cs

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
      c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
    });
```

Comment: This option is deprecated in the Swashbuckle. It is recommended to use the ASP.NET Core option and then Swashbuckle can reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

There were a number of shortcomings I found in the other answers for what we were looking for, so I thought I'd supply my own take on this. We're using ASP.NET Core 3.1 with System.Text.Json, but our approach works irrespective of the JSON serializer used.

Our goal was to accept lower-camel-cased enum string values in both the ASP.NET Core API as well as document the same in Swagger. We're currently making use of `[DataContract]` and `[EnumMember]`, so the approach is to take the lower-camel-cased value from the EnumMember value property and use that across the board.

Our sample enum:

```
[DataContract]
public class enum Colors
{
  [EnumMember(Value="brightPink")]
  BrightPink,
  [EnumMember(Value="blue")]
  Blue
}
```

We'll use the EnumMember values in Swashbuckle by using an ISchemaFilter as in the following:

```
public class DescribeEnumMemberValues : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.Type.IsEnum)
        {
            schema.Enum.Clear();

            //Retrieve each of the values decorated with an EnumMember attribute
            foreach (var member in context.Type.GetMembers())
            {
                var memberAttr = member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
                if (memberAttr != null)
                {
                    var attr = (EnumMemberAttribute) memberAttr;
                    schema.Enum.Add(new OpenApiString(attr.Value));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We're using a [third-party NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EnumExtensions.System.Text.Json) (GitHub [repo](https://github.com/StefH/System.Text.Json.EnumExtensions)) to ensure that this naming scheme is also utilized in ASP.NET Core. Configure it in Startup.cs within ConfigureServices with:

```
services.AddControllers()
  .AddJsonOptions(opt => opt.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverterWithAttributeSupport()));
```

Finally, we need to register our ISchemaFilter in Swashbuckle, so also add the following also in ConfigureServices():

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
  c.SchemaFilter<DescribeEnumMemberValues>();
});
```

Comment: `GetMembers()` would be better as `GetMembers(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)` to limit to only the actual declared enum properties such as "Blue". I also adapted the "else" case to return the Member.Name if there is no `[EnumMember]` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If the version of the swagger were 5.5.x, then you need to:

1. install: Install-Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft -Version 5.5.0
2. services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();

Reference: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#systemtextjson-stj-vs-newtonsoft

Comment: This worked for me. If you are using Newtonsoft Json in your asp.net core project. The you need to explicitly this. Thanks @user30844147

Comment: A very important step.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unchase.Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Extensions) that handles all the tweaks suggested here. It particularly useful if you do **not** want to change how enums are serialized (because text might be more brittle than a integer value) but just need more documentation in the Swagger description.

The nuget also works with .NET 7 minimal APIs:

```
using Unchase.Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Extensions.Extensions;
...
builder.Services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.AddEnumsWithValuesFixFilters();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**.Net Core 3.0**

```
   using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

 services
    .AddMvc(options =>
    {
     options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
     })
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter()))
```

Comment: It is using Newtonsoft instead of new asp.net core JSON serialization.

Answer (score 0):

**ASP NET SOLUTION**

In my api docs one enum was still shown as int despite the property being marked with `StringEnumConverter`. We couldn't afford using the global setting for all enums mentioned above. Adding this line in SwaggerConfig solved the issue:

```
c.MapType<ContactInfoType>(() => new Schema { type = "string", @enum = Enum.GetNames(typeof(ContactInfoType))});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate enums with name and value you can use this solution.

Prerequisites:

- you're using [NSwag](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag) or [Openapi-generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/templating/) to generate API client
- you have an old Web Api project (pre .NET Core) and use [Swashbuckle.WebApi](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi) package

Register SchemaFilter:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    .EnableSwagger("/swagger", c =>
    {
        c.SchemaFilter<EnumSchemaFilter>();
    });
```

EnumSchemaFilter:

```
public class EnumSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, Type type)
    {
        var enumProperties = schema.properties?.Where(p => p.Value.@enum != null);
        if(enumProperties != null)
        {
            foreach (var property in enumProperties)
            {
                var array = Enum.GetNames(type.GetProperty(property.Key).PropertyType).ToArray();
                property.Value.vendorExtensions.Add("x-enumNames", array); // NSwag
                property.Value.vendorExtensions.Add("x-enum-varnames", array); // Openapi-generator
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems to get the answers for Swagger and .NET for version 6.x working. I wanted to continue using integer values for enums, but also display a list of possible values (in a readable format). So here is my modified version (includes parts of some answers), maybe it saves some time for some of you ;)

P.S. There is still some room for improvement, you should also check if the logic of the method "GetEnumTypeByName" fits for you. In my case I wanted to primarily update descriptions only for project internal and unique enums.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Any;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Models.Api;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;

/// <summary>
/// Add enum value descriptions to Swagger
/// </summary>
public class SwaggerEnumDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        // add enum descriptions to result models
        foreach (var property in swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas)
        {
            var propertyEnums = property.Value.Enum;
            if (propertyEnums is { Count: > 0 })
            {
                property.Value.Description += DescribeEnum(propertyEnums, property.Key);
            }
        }

        if (swaggerDoc.Paths.Count <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        // add enum descriptions to input parameters
        foreach (var pathItem in swaggerDoc.Paths.Values)
        {
            DescribeEnumParameters(pathItem.Parameters);

            var affectedOperations = new List<OperationType> { OperationType.Get, OperationType.Post, OperationType.Put };

            foreach (var operation in pathItem.Operations)
            {
                if (affectedOperations.Contains(operation.Key))
                {
                    DescribeEnumParameters(operation.Value.Parameters);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void DescribeEnumParameters(IList<OpenApiParameter> parameters)
    {
        if (parameters == null) return;

        foreach (var param in parameters)
        {
            if (param.Schema.Reference != null)
            {
                param.Description += DescribeEnum(param.Schema.Reference.Id);
            }
        }
    }

    private static Type GetEnumTypeByName(string enumTypeName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(enumTypeName))
        {
            return null;
        }

        try
        {
            var projectNamespaceRoot = "MyProject.";

            return AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                            .GetAssemblies()
                            .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                            .Single(x => x.FullName != null
                                      && x.FullName.StartsWith(projectNamespaceRoot)
                                      && x.Name == enumTypeName);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException _)
        {
            throw new ApiException($"SwaggerDoc: Can not find a unique Enum for specified typeName '{enumTypeName}'. Please provide a more unique enum name.");
        }
    }

    private static string DescribeEnum(IEnumerable<IOpenApiAny> enums, string propertyTypeName)
    {
        var enumType = GetEnumTypeByName(propertyTypeName);

        if (enumType == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var parsedEnums = new List<OpenApiInteger>();
        foreach (var @enum in enums)
        {
            if (@enum is OpenApiInteger enumInt)
            {
                parsedEnums.Add(enumInt);
            }
        }

        return string.Join(", ", parsedEnums.Select(x => $"{x} = {Enum.GetName(enumType, x.Value)}"));
    }
}
```

As already mentioned by others, you have to register this Filter inside your Swagger setup:

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                // some configuration
            });
              
            options.DocumentFilter<SwaggerEnumDocumentFilter>();
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

In .Net 6 with NSwag and System.Text.Json for me works:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews()
       .AddJsonOptions(o => o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()))
```

and

```
services.AddOpenApiDocument(configure =>
{
       ...
       configure.GenerateEnumMappingDescription = true;
});
```

It accepts int-s and strings, generates enums in open-api and .ts client with names and show enums with names in SwaggerUI

```
export enum PaymentDirection {
    Input = "Input",
    Output = "Output",
}
```