# C# NSwag and swagger-codegen with Enums

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-codegen, nswag

I have a .Net Core v2.1 Web API which uses NSwag to generate its Swagger Json.

I have a response model as such -

```
public class LoginResponse
{
    public LoginResult LoginResult { get; set; }
}

public enum LoginResult
{
    AwaitingEmailConfirmation = 0,
    Locked = 1,
    Failed = 2,
    Success = 3
}
```

Which generates the Swagger JSON of -

```
"definitions":{  
"LoginResponse":{  
   "type":"object",
   "additionalProperties":false,
   "required":[  
      "loginResult"
   ],
   "properties":{  
      "loginResult":{  
         "$ref":"#/definitions/LoginResult"
      }
   }
},
"LoginResult":{  
   "type":"integer",
   "description":"",
   "x-enumNames":[  
      "AwaitingEmailConfirmation",
      "Locked",
      "Failed",
      "Success"
   ],
   "enum":[  
      0,
      1,
      2,
      3
   ]
},
```

and when running swagger codegen on the JSON I get the following LoginResult model in my IO.Swagger project for C# (targetFramework 5.0 chosen) -

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]

public enum LoginResult
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Enum _0 for value: 0
    /// </summary>
    [EnumMember(Value = "0")]
    _0 = 1,

    /// <summary>
    /// Enum _1 for value: 1
    /// </summary>
    [EnumMember(Value = "1")]
    _1 = 2,

    /// <summary>
    /// Enum _2 for value: 2
    /// </summary>
    [EnumMember(Value = "2")]
    _2 = 3,

    /// <summary>
    /// Enum _3 for value: 3
    /// </summary>
    [EnumMember(Value = "3")]
    _3 = 4
  }

}
```

Could someone help describe how I get the enums to generate with the same names etc as the original LoginResult Model in the IO.Swagger generated client code using swagger-codegen?

Comment: See https://github.com/RSuter/NJsonSchema/wiki/Enums

Comment: Can you just remove the numeric assignment in your original enum definition? It's not necessary

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452468/swagger-ui-web-api-documentation-present-enums-as-strings/55541764#55541764

Answer (score 7):

You can use this code in your start up:

```
services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false).AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
        });
```

Answer (score 5):

Using Nswag 13.10.7 and .netcore 3.1

Edit your `Startup.ConfigureServices` to something like

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
                });
             ...
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

im using the 14.x versioon of NSwag.
seems like thtat this issue happens as well.
if i add the converters, as proposed - i still end up with crappy enum values generated.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35646431)