# SwaggerUI not display enum summary description, C# .net core?

Tags: c#, enums, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

I used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#xml-comments to show my classes summaries description in SwaggerUI, it's OK but not show `enum` summary description !
My `startup.cs`

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{   
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "My App-Service",
        Description = "My Description",
    });
    c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml"));  
    c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
});
```

My `enum`:

```
public enum GenderEnum
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Man Description
    /// </summary>
    Man = 1,

    /// <summary>
    /// Woman Description
    /// </summary>
    Woman = 2
}
```

It shows something like following:
[image: Swagger UI enum]

I want to show `Man Description` and `Woman Description` in SwaggerUI
like this:

```
Man = 1, Man Description
Woman = 2,  Woman Description
```

I'm using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v4.0.1` package

Comment: this is an open issue in swagger https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3873 or https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/685

Comment: @Mohammad just to clarify - do you mean you want to see both the enum values AND descriptions of each value? E.g. something like: "`Man` - Man Description, `Woman` - Woman Description".

Comment: @Helen, Yes exactly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger UI Web Api documentation Present enums as strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452468/swagger-ui-web-api-documentation-present-enums-as-strings), specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43074037/113116).

Comment: To recap the ^^ linked answer - OpenAPI Specification currently [does not support enum value descriptions](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/348); the workaround is to include those descriptions in the description of the enum or parameter itself.

Answer (score 9):

This solution allows for

- Show underlying value as well as name/description
- Handle multiple xml documentation files, but only process docs once.
- Customization of the layout without code change

Here's the class...

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Swagger schema filter to modify description of enum types so they
    /// show the XML docs attached to each member of the enum.
    /// </summary>
    public class DescribeEnumMembers : ISchemaFilter
    {
        private readonly XDocument xmlComments;
        private readonly string assemblyName;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize schema filter.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xmlComments">Document containing XML docs for enum members.</param>
        public DescribeEnumMembers(XDocument xmlComments)
        {
            this.xmlComments = xmlComments;
            this.assemblyName = DetermineAssembly(xmlComments);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Pre-amble to use before the enum items
        /// </summary>
        public static string Prefix { get; set; } = "<p>Possible values:</p>";

        /// <summary>
        /// Format to use, 0 : value, 1: Name, 2: Description
        /// </summary>
        public static string Format { get; set; } = "<b>{0} - {1}</b>: {2}";

        /// <summary>
        /// Apply this schema filter.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="schema">Target schema object.</param>
        /// <param name="context">Schema filter context.</param>
        public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            var type = context.Type;

            // Only process enums and...
            if (!type.IsEnum)
            {
                return;
            }

            // ...only the comments defined in their origin assembly
            if (type.Assembly.GetName().Name != assemblyName)
            {
                return;
            }
            var sb = new StringBuilder(schema.Description);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Prefix))
            {
                sb.AppendLine(Prefix);
            }

            sb.AppendLine("<ul>");

            // TODO: Handle flags better e.g. Hex formatting
            foreach (var name in Enum.GetValues(type))
            {
                // Allows for large enums
                var value = Convert.ToInt64(name);
                var fullName = $"F:{type.FullName}.{name}";

                var description = xmlComments.XPathEvaluate(
                    $"normalize-space(//member[@name = '{fullName}']/summary/text())"
                ) as string;

                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("<li>" + Format + "</li>", value, name, description));
            }

            sb.AppendLine("</ul>");

            schema.Description = sb.ToString();
        }

        private string DetermineAssembly(XDocument doc)
        {
            var name = ((IEnumerable)doc.XPathEvaluate("/doc/assembly")).Cast<XElement>().ToList().FirstOrDefault();
            
            return name?.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

and utilization...

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    ...
    
    // See https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/86
    var dir = new DirectoryInfo(AppContext.BaseDirectory);
    
    foreach (var fi in dir.EnumerateFiles("*.xml"))
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load(fi.FullName);
        c.IncludeXmlComments(() => new XPathDocument(doc.CreateReader()), true);
        c.SchemaFilter<DescribeEnumMembers>(doc);
    }
});
```

This then reports as

[image]

Answer (score 8):

As of June/2021 OpenApi now supports this and you can extend Swagger to show the details. Here is my code for C# on .NET 5.0.

First define the schema filter in a file (call it `DescribeEnumMembers.cs` and be sure to change `YourNamespace` to the name of your namespace):

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;

namespace YourNamespace
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Swagger schema filter to modify description of enum types so they
  /// show the XML docs attached to each member of the enum.
  /// </summary>
  public class DescribeEnumMembers: ISchemaFilter
  {
    private readonly XDocument mXmlComments;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize schema filter.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="argXmlComments">Document containing XML docs for enum members.</param>
    public DescribeEnumMembers(XDocument argXmlComments)
      => mXmlComments = argXmlComments;

    /// <summary>
    /// Apply this schema filter.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="argSchema">Target schema object.</param>
    /// <param name="argContext">Schema filter context.</param>
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema argSchema, SchemaFilterContext argContext) {
      var EnumType = argContext.Type;

      if(!EnumType.IsEnum) return;

      var sb = new StringBuilder(argSchema.Description);

      sb.AppendLine("<p>Possible values:</p>");
      sb.AppendLine("<ul>");

      foreach(var EnumMemberName in Enum.GetNames(EnumType)) {
        var FullEnumMemberName = $"F:{EnumType.FullName}.{EnumMemberName}";

        var EnumMemberDescription = mXmlComments.XPathEvaluate(
          $"normalize-space(//member[@name = '{FullEnumMemberName}']/summary/text())"
        ) as string;

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(EnumMemberDescription)) continue;

        sb.AppendLine($"<li><b>{EnumMemberName}</b>: {EnumMemberDescription}</li>");
      }

      sb.AppendLine("</ul>");

      argSchema.Description = sb.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

Then enable it in your ASP.NET `ConfigureServices()` method. Here is my code after snipping out the parts that don't matter for this exercise:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection argServices) {
  // ...<snip other code>

  argServices.AddSwaggerGen(SetSwaggerGenOptions);

  // ...<snip other code>

  return;

  // ...<snip other code>

  void SetSwaggerGenOptions(SwaggerGenOptions argOptions) {
    // ...<snip other code>

    AddXmlDocs();
    return;

    void AddXmlDocs() {
      // generate paths for the XML doc files in the assembly's directory.
      var XmlDocPaths = Directory.GetFiles(
        path: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
        searchPattern: "YourAssemblyNameHere*.xml"
      );

      // load the XML docs for processing.
      var XmlDocs = (
        from DocPath in XmlDocPaths select XDocument.Load(DocPath)
      ).ToList();

      // ...<snip other code>

      // add pre-processed XML docs to Swagger.
      foreach(var doc in XmlDocs) {
        argOptions.IncludeXmlComments(() => new XPathDocument(doc.CreateReader()), true);

        // apply schema filter to add description of enum members.
        argOptions.SchemaFilter<DescribeEnumMembers>(doc);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Remember to change `"YourAssemblyNameHere*.xml"` to match your assembly name. The important line that enables the schema filter is:

```cs
argOptions.SchemaFilter<DescribeEnumMembers>(doc);
```

...which MUST be called AFTER the following line:

```cs
argOptions.IncludeXmlComments(() => new XPathDocument(doc.CreateReader()), true);
```

Using the above code, if you have an enum type defined like this for example:

```cs
  /// <summary>
  /// Setting to control when a no-match report is returned when searching.
  /// </summary>
  public enum NoMatchReportSetting
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Return no-match report only if the search query has no match.
    /// </summary>
    IfNoMatch = 0,
    /// <summary>
    /// Always return no-match report even if the search query has a match.
    /// </summary>
    Always = 1,
    /// <summary>
    /// Never return no-match report even if search query has no match.
    /// </summary>
    No = 99
  }
```

The Swagger documentation will end up showing a description of each enum member as part of the description of the enum type itself:

[image: swagger doc screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this does not seem to be supported in the OpenAPI specification. There is an open [Github issue for this](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/348).

There is also an open [Github issue for Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi/issues/1290).
However, in this issue there is a workaround to create a schema filter, which at least shows the enum value comments in the enum type description.

Answer (score -6):

I solved this using a description attribute. Here is an example usage:

```
public enum GenderEnum
{
    [Description("Man Description")]
    Man = 1,

    [Description("Woman Description")]
    Woman = 2
}
```

Comment: What changes occured within the UI as a result of adding these annotations?

Comment: This does not do anything in my SwaggerUI.

Comment: Description must have been setup already
You might be able to post an example as an answer if its easier than the other answers