# Swashbuckle - treat string as enum in swagger documentation

Tags: c#, enums, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm using FluentValidation and I want to receive only my custom errors from fluent validators. That's why all my properties in requests classes are strings. However, I would also like to have better documentation for enum types.

Here is my sample request:

```
 public class AddNewPaymentRequest
 {
     [EnumDataType(typeof(PaymentStatus))]
     public string PaymentStatus { get; set; }

     public string Id { get; set; }
 }
```

And sample enum:

```
 public enum PaymentStatus
 {
     Unknown,
     New,
     Pending,
     Completed
 }
```

And controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> PostAsync([FromBody] AddNewPaymentRequest request)
{
   ...
}
```

I'd like to have this EnumDataType working as an information for Swagger to display enum description, instead of string destripction. I want Swagger to treat this string as an enum.

Actual result:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnh7V.png)

Expected result:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rc1qA.png)

Is there any possibility to configure Swashbuckle in this way?

Comment: did you able to resolve it? or you followed the answer below?

Comment: not yes, i want to try to solve it with int and not string

Answer (score 3):

I guess we are talking about .NET Core

If it is ok for you it would be a possibility to define it explicity as enum instead of string

```
 public class AddNewPaymentRequest
 {
     //[EnumDataType(typeof(PaymentStatus))]
     //public string PaymentStatus { get; set; }

     public PaymentStatus PaymentStatus { get; set; }

     public string Id { get; set; }
 }
```

Then you could define how SwaggerGen treats the enums

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings(); } );
```

If you run into issues with the serialized/deserialzed enums (by Newtonsoft.Json) when receiving/sending data at/from you api you can take more controller about the conversion (if necessary)

```
 [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter))]
 public enum PaymentStatus
 {
     [EnumMember(Value = "Unknwon")]
     Unknown,

     [EnumMember(Value = "New")]
     New,

     [EnumMember(Value = "Pending")]
     Pending,

     [EnumMember(Value = "Completed")]
     Completed,

     [EnumMember(Value = "something_different_with_underline")]
     SomethingDifferentWithUnderline
 }
```

Mind that ToString() for these enums may result in different strings (with/without) underlines

Comment: is there a way to do this with INT?

Comment: The Swashbuckle's method DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings() is obsolete. You should configure your serializer instead, swagger will use it automatically.

Comment: @elperegrino any sample for NET6 Minimal api?

Comment: See here how to configure the JSON serializer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55541764/10069673

Answer (score 1):

Swaggers supports only `RequiredAttribute`, `ObsoleteAttribute` and `MetaData` (for external class).
So there's no way to describe accepted values besides writing something like this:

`/// <summary> Allowed values are....`

Comment: Do we have the following in Swashbuckle? https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/enums/

Comment: @tnk479 - I'm talking about C# code that describes the API. Later on it's used to generate Swagger's documentation and OpenApi.

Answer (score 0):

These answers all effectively say "you can't do that, here are other options." Well, you can do it and here's how.

Create an attribute named `OpenApiEnumAttribute` like so:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Used in conjunction with OpenApiEnumSchemaFilter to apply the enum property
/// to an OpenAPI schema.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class OpenApiEnumAttribute : Attribute
{
    public OpenApiEnumAttribute(params string[] enumOptions)
    {
        EnumOptions = enumOptions;
    }
    
    public OpenApiEnumAttribute(Type enoom)
    {
        if (!enoom.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Type not an enum", nameof(enoom));
        }
        EnumOptions = Enum.GetNames(enoom);
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Options for values that the property can have
    /// </summary>
    public string[] EnumOptions { get; }
}
```

Then also create a Schema Filter like so:

```cs
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Any;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;

/// <summary>
/// Applies the enum property to an OpenAPI schema. Most useful to constrain
/// strings to be a specific value.
/// </summary>
public class OpenApiEnumSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.MemberInfo == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        var enumAnnotation = context.MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(OpenApiEnumAttribute), false)
            .Cast<OpenApiEnumAttribute>()
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (enumAnnotation == null) return;

        schema.Enum = enumAnnotation.EnumOptions.Select(option => new OpenApiString(option))
            .Cast<IOpenApiAny>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Finally in your Startup.cs (or wherever you call `AddSwaggerGen`:

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(config => { config.SchemaFilter<OpenApiEnumSchemaFilter>(); } );
```

Based on your example you can now use it like so:

```cs
public class AddNewPaymentRequest
{
    [OpenApiEnum(typeof(PaymentStatus))]
    public string PaymentStatus { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```