# NSwag Enum generation starts from 0

Tags: asp.net-core, web, swagger, swagger-ui, nswag

I have an Enum declared on a API like this :

```
 public enum Currencies
    {
        RON = 1,
        USD,
        EUR,
        GBP,
        CHF,
        PLN,
        CAD,
        HUF,
        NOK,
        SEK
    }
```

but when I use NSwag to generate a HttpClient, it starts from 0 and I obtain this:

```
public enum Currencies
    {

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"RON")]
        RON = 0,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"USD")]
        USD = 1,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"EUR")]
        EUR = 2,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"GBP")]
        GBP = 3,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"CHF")]
        CHF = 4,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"PLN")]
        PLN = 5,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"CAD")]
        CAD = 6,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"HUF")]
        HUF = 7,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"NOK")]
        NOK = 8,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"SEK")]
        SEK = 9,

    }
```

the generated one starts from 0, while the initial one stars from 1. This leads to validation problems when I try to call the api. how can I map this ?

Comment: Did you get the solution for this. I am also facing the same problem :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some solutions can be found in Stackoverflow, but I had struggle with them and will like to resume how to pass from what you have here to the solution.
What is really important, it's to **remove** this code you certainly have:

```
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
        });
```

Or may be the following line in your swagger config

```
c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings()
```

When you do that, your generated code will look like that

```
public enum Currencies
{

    _1 = 1,

    _2 = 2,

    _3 = 3,

    _4 = 4,

    _5 = 5,

    _6 = 6,

    _7 = 7,

    _8 = 8,

    _9 = 9
}
```

Now your values are correct, the issue is about the name.
So you can use the solution describe here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71526271/9466394
and implement the NSwagEnumExtensionSchemaFilter and the NSwagEnumOpenApiExtension whitch add the "x-enumNames" schema details.

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;

/// <summary>
/// Adds extra schema details for an enum in the swagger.json i.e. x-enumNames (used by NSwag to generate Enums for C# client)
/// https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1234
/// </summary>
public class NSwagEnumExtensionSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (schema is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(schema));

        if (context is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        if (context.Type.IsEnum)
            schema.Extensions.Add("x-enumNames", new NSwagEnumOpenApiExtension(context));
    }
}
```

---

```
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.OpenApi;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Writers;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;

public class NSwagEnumOpenApiExtension : IOpenApiExtension
{
    private readonly SchemaFilterContext _context;
    public NSwagEnumOpenApiExtension(SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Write(IOpenApiWriter writer, OpenApiSpecVersion specVersion)
    {
        string[] enums = Enum.GetNames(_context.Type);
        JsonSerializerOptions options = new() { WriteIndented = true };
        string value = JsonSerializer.Serialize(enums, options);
        writer.WriteRaw(value);
    }
}
```

---

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    ...
    c.SchemaFilter<NSwagEnumExtensionSchemaFilter>();
});
```

Now your generated code will look like:

```
    public enum Currencies
    {
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"RON")]
        RON = 1,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"USD")]
        USD = 2,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"EUR")]
        EUR = 3,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"GBP")]
        GBP = 4,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"CHF")]
        CHF = 5,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"PLN")]
        PLN = 6,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"CAD")]
        CAD = 7,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"HUF")]
        HUF = 8,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"NOK")]
        NOK = 9,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"SEK")]
        SEK = 10
  }
```

You can also add the EnumDocumentFilter if you want your swagger totally clean