# How to fully reflect Enums to client code using Swagger REST API

Tags: vb.net, enums, swagger, rest

I'm building a REST API and a lot of the objects it returns are designed with a number of `Enum`s for various settings.

Having read up on it, and in particular using advice from this SO Question:

[Swagger UI Web Api documentation Present enums as strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452468/swagger-ui-web-api-documentation-present-enums-as-strings/49941775)

I have set up my Global.asax to enable Swagger with the `DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings` option:

[image]

(It should be noted here that the parent project which provides the API is a .NET Framework application, written in VB which I *do* plan to convert to a .NET Core application but being a big project, migration will take time, so code above is for .NET Framework VB, whereas code below, the consuming Client is a .NET Core website application using C#)

The client code (adding using Visual Studio > Add Rest Client (Swagger)) generates all the objects correctly, and Intellisense knows the `string` options for the `Enum`s:

[image]

Yet, when I `dump` the JSON object fetched by the API, the `Enum` properties have integer values represented as strings:

[image]

In this instance, the API is returning some image data; images have 4 size variants and the Image.Size class gives the user information about the sizes. `SizeType` is an `Enum` used to determine which image to use for different purposes.

For the convenience of the clients using this API I would like the `Enum` type to be reflected and produced by the generated API code, or at least, the `Enum` properties be string values that correspond to the `Enum` name, thus a bit of code like:

```
i.Sizes.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SizeType.Equals("Thumb"))
```

or

```
i.Sizes.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SizeType = SizeType.Thumb)
```

Will be more intuitive for the user. Currently, neither of the above find the Thumbnail image size that it should, the code to fetch this Thumbnail needs to be:

```
i.Sizes.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SizeType = "3")
```

Obviously that isn't as intuitive as the above examples, and I am not sure why, or what, if any, `Swagger` option would change it.

Comment: Yes, I realise `Enums` are just a named integer, but the whole point of naming them is for simpler, more intuitive coding, which I would like to be reflected by the generated API code. When `DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings` is set the Swagger documentation adds the names to the `Enum` and makes the property values strings, this makes it partially easier for the coding in the client app, but is not   fully reflected named Enum.

Comment: "4 size variants" yet you list 7 "possible values" which is it?

Comment: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/enums/ might help you with the value vs description of the enums for the OData/swagger schema

Comment: This is related but I am not 100% sure it answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/q/36452468/125981

Comment: Keep in mind one of the important values of an Enum is the compile time checking.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and links, but none quite answer it. The related question you post is the same one I referenced in my original question, that did help and got me as far as I have got. It presents the ENUM values as strings to the user for the purpose of making requests to the API, which helps but it doesn’t make the REST client code generate the ENUM types as I’d prefer for client use. It surprises me since it generates all classes and properties, why not ENUMs?  Interesting article on “why ENUMs”: https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-an-enum-958326