# Swagger .Net Core Enum Query Parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, openapi

Is there any reason why it always returns a validation error?

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Here's my enum schema filter code:

```
public class EnumSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema model, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.Type.IsEnum)
        {
            model.Enum.Clear();
            Enum.GetNames(context.Type)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(n => model.Enum.Add(new OpenApiString(n)));
        }
    }
}
```

Enum Model:

```
public enum QuoteStatus
{
    New = 0,
    Confirmed = 10,
    Completed = 100
}
```

Controller:

```
 [Route("/v{v:apiVersion}/Campaigns/{propertyNo}/[controller]", Name = nameof(GetCampaignQuote))]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Quote>> GetCampaignQuote([FromRoute]int propertyNo, [FromQuery]QuoteStatus status)
    {
        var result = await _iQuoteService.GetCampaignQuote(propertyNo, status);

        if (result == null)
            return BadRequest();

        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Is there anyway to convert those enum string to integer data type? Or is there a way to change the data type of the parameter to be an enum type?

Comment: End point is different in swagger than the controller method.

Comment: That's not the problem but yea I have added the route for you. @Imran

Comment: Please check this, it might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/55541764/9695286

Comment: So, your problem is that you want to pass string data in swagger UI and receive it in your action as Enum, right?

Comment: yes correct @MuhammadVakili

Comment: Thank you @Karan!!!!!! You're so GOLD!!! I forgot to add Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft