# Swagger enum with names

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, swagger

Is it possilbe in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger (6.1.1) to get such enum with names? I need better names for generate API client for frontend app.

```
public enum BasketResourceEnum
{
    Stocks = 1,
    Currencies
}
```

Now I get such representation in json, I need name instead of int values

```
  "BasketResourceEnum": {
    "enum": [
      1,
      2
    ],
    "type": "integer",
    "format": "int32"
  },
```

Comment: Maybe that could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452468/swagger-ui-web-api-documentation-present-enums-as-strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => 
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter()));
```

Comment: How to do that only for specific enums? (I don't want to mess with existing api calls, I only want new enums that are added to the project to be serialized and deserialized as strings)

Comment: @ThanasisIoannidis - You could either opt-in to string conversion by placing a `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` attribute on your new enums or override StringEnumConverter's CanConvert method to specify the types you want to convert as strings.

Answer (score 4):

And if you prefer not to choose to serialize enum values as strings but just have the names of their members described in Swagger, you can you the [this nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unchase.Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Extensions).

In a minimal API you can:

```
using Unchase.Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Extensions.Extensions;
...
builder.Services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.AddEnumsWithValuesFixFilters();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer to use `System.Text.Json`:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
...
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
```