# .NET: Declare an API return type of enumerated strings

Tags: .net, string, enums, swagger, swashbuckle

C# allows declaration of enums:

```cs
namespace examlimiter.Models
{
    public enum OperationStatus : ushort
    {
        Pending = 0,
        InProgress = 1,
        Success = 2,
        Error = 3,
        Warning = 4
    }
}
```

However it does not allow the declaration of string enums, which is a problem when working with Swagger/Swashbuckle.

If I define this route in a .NET controller:

```
[Route("api/testonly")]
[HttpGet]
public OperationStatus GetOperationStatus()
  {
    return OperationStatus.InProgress;
  }
```

And generate an API based on it with Swashbuckle, this is the result:

```json
{
  "responses": {
    "200": {
      "description": "Success",
      "content": {
        "text/plain": {
          "schema": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/OperationStatus"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

...

{
  "OperationStatus": {
    "enum": [
      0,
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4
    ],
    "type": "integer",
    "format": "int32"
  }
}
```

This return type is not very meaningful to a consumer of the API.

I hoped that if I configured the backend to instead return a string, I could use a data annotation to generate something more like this:

```json
{
  "OperationStatus": {
    "enum": [
      "Pending",
      "InProgress",
      "Success",
      "Error",
      "Warning"
    ],
    "type": "string"
  }
}
```

Is it viable to do this with modern Swagger and .NET?

Comment: What library/framework do you use - Swashbucke, NSwag, Swagger-Net, something else?

Comment: @Helen .NET with Swagger -- is this the same thing as Swagger-Net?

Comment: No. "Swagger" is a combined name for lots of different tools/libraries. Often, solutions depend on which exactly library you use because e.g. they might use different annotations. Do you have [Swashbucke](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore), [NSwag](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag), [Swagger-Net](https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net) or a similar library in your project dependencies?

Comment: @Helen thank you. It is Swashbuckle. I've updated my question

Comment: Check out the answers here and see if they apply to your case: [Swagger UI Web Api documentation Present enums as strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36452468/113116)